# Install Gensim in python3

Tags: python, gensim

I have two versions of python: python2, python3.

When I install gensim it goes to python2
 I install it with the following comand

```
sudo pip3 install --upgrade gensim
```

how can I install it in python3?

Comment: `pip3 install` will install to python3 not python2, unless you configured in the wrong way.

Comment: @Vineeth. Getting it that wrong would actually be mildly impressive.

Comment: yeah maybe it did install to python3 and op didn't check properly. or Might be running a different python3 interpreter.

Comment: What is your OS? What makes you think that `sudo pip3 install --upgrade gensim` didn't work? (How did you check if `gensim` was installed under your Python3 environment?) Also, it is generally best practice to use a "Python virtual environment" per project, installing libraries like `gensim`(and its many dependencies) into those, rather than into your system's Python(s). In that case, you'd create a virtual environment, activate it, install `gensim` there (without using `sudo`).

Answer (score 1):

You can install it in python3 with the following command:

```
sudo python3 -m pip install --upgrade gensim
```

Comment: python3.7: No module named pip

Comment: You should then install `pip`, this differs per OS. Look here to see how to install it on your OS. https://www.tecmint.com/install-pip-in-linux/

Comment: In recent versions of Python 3, you shouldn't need to install `pip`: it's already there. See <https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html>. (If your Python 3.7 doesn't show pip as installed, something else is very broken in its installation.)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using a `virtualenv` with only python3 in it. You can create it using

`virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3 myenv`

then activate it using `source` command.

```
source myenv/bin/activate
```

now you can install using `pip install gensim` that will install it to the python3 specific to that virtual environment.

Comment: In recent versions of Python 3, `virtualenv` isn't necessary (as the `venv` tool is built in). See <https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html>.